# NineOldAdroids Animation curveTo dp insted pixels

Tags: android, android-animation, nineoldandroids

I have an animation but it looks different on different screen sizes, how to adjust it so
that the function curveTo does take 'dp' instead of pixels?

And also if someone has an idea how to slow down it in the corner points, I am simulating falling leaf animation.

```
        ImageView fallingLeave = (ImageView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.lemonpiece1_large);
            mButtonProxy = AnimatorProxy.wrap(fallingLeave);

            // Set up the path we're animating along
            AnimatorPath path = new AnimatorPath();
            path.moveTo(0,0);
            path.curveTo(0, 0, 0 , 80, -80, 70);
            path.curveTo(-80, 70, -80, 120, 80, 140);
            path.curveTo(80, 140, 80, 190, -80, 210);
```